# CSS, jQuery - forcing clip-path in IE

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, clip-path

I've got little problem with clip-path (i know that IE doesn't support that).
I've found some solutions for clip-pathing image but that is not the case - i need to do it with the whole section.

But maybe there is some other solution? Basically i need shape like this:
[image]

Pink area is the end of the first section, and the grey one is begining of the next section. (I've achieved that shapes with clip-path, but unfortunately it doesn't work in IE).

Maybe there is some solution to use jQuery to force the clip-path in IE? I'm open to all sugestions :)

Thnx for help!

Comment: You should let us know which versions of IE you want to support. IE8 and greater, IE10 and lower... the solutions given will be dependant on what you need to support.

Comment: R. Chappell - mostly i wan't to support Edge and maybe IE 10 - no need to support previous versions.

Comment: There's also a Polyfill available: https://github.com/andrusieczko/clip-path-polygon

Comment: Yes i've already used that for Firefox, but still not working in IE - just trying out your border line (;)) solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really force a browser to use functionality that it doesn't support. However, it is possible to reproduce what you are after but in a different way, using a couple of divs, big borders and transform.

```css
.border {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden; /* hide borders */
}

.line {
  border-top: 500px solid #f6c; /* Fill top with pink */
  border-bottom: 500px solid #ccc; /* Fill bottom with grey */
  width: 1000px; /* Overflow the container so borders fill space */
  height: 10px; /* White line height */
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: -350px; /* Border top height, minus position relative to border */
  left: -200px; /* hang off the edge so borders fill space */
  transform: rotate(-2deg); /* Rotate white line */
}
```

```html
<div class="border">
    <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

We get an effect similar to what you want which should work in IE9 and above. I know it's not exactly what you were after but it does seem to achieve the same result and maybe useful.

Comment: that is a really good solution for what i've posted - thnx. But i've forgot to mention that is not all the functionallity i need. For example i need to the elements got overflow hidden in some cases, like on this screen: http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img922/3891/ocVgqo.jpg i've tried a lot of different aproaches and could not get the result...

Comment: also, i need something to achieve this effect: http://imageshack.com/a/img921/3711/hMT0TD.jpg it's overflow hidden with clip-path added - is there any way to get this in IE or Edge?

Comment: You can do similar tricks, for example the first version you can set your image as the background and only fill the box with the line having only a bottom border. The second option, I'd just use an image and use background-size to scale it properly.

Comment: Thnx a lot! Honestly i didn't want to use image, but i think there is no other option.